# Docker: no processes, no containers, for every port: “bind: address already in use”

Tags: docker, networking, server, port, firewall

I get the

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint beautiful_jang (..): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp [::]:53007: bind: address already in use.
```

error for

- any container image
- any port
- with no other docker daemons running
- with no processes listening on any port (apart from mdns and systemd-resolved)
- with iptables -F(lushed) and docker daemon running with or without ipv6 support
- with no meaningful error message in docker logs, even with debug mode

I’m able to start processes that bind to ports `nc -l 53007`.

I’m running Clear Linux (latest update 39540) on a simple system that has been running docker for the last 5 years.

Here are running systemd services:

(removed because it triggered a spam filter)

I’m really out of ideas here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `127.0.0.1:53007:53007` instead of `53007:53007` for port definitions. I was told its related to an upgrade the new docker version 24.0.2.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Can you please tell me where you found this answer? This just started happening to me on Clearlinux

Comment: In case someone else is having this issue, its not always 127.0.0.1, in my case it was a local private static ip assigned to the docker host. for example 172.0.91.52